# How to load resources from classpath matching a pattern with Quarkus

Tags: java, classpath, quarkus

I'm trying to load all resources containing a certain pattern (e.g. *.properties) from classpath. Therefore I've tried to use

```
ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
ArrayList<URL> resources = Collections.list(classLoader.getResources("")); 
resources.add(classLoader.getResource("org"));
```

In the next step I iterated through the list of URL-resources, create a proper `java.nio.FileSystem` and use a `PathMatcher` to find the required resources.

This solution does not work for the following reason:

- resources in the root-directory will not be found since `classloader.getResource()` does not work with `""`, `null` or `/`
- the prod-profile of course behaves completly different to the dev-profile

Is there a way in Quarkus to load a list of resources from classpath using a pattern.

thanks in advance &
best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem the following way:

First of all I've added this maven dependency to my project:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

The library provides a class called `ClasspathHelper` which has been used as described in the following code snippet.

```
Collection<URL> classpathURLs = ClasspathHelper.forPackage("org", (ClassLoader[]) null);

Path path = null;
FileSystem fileSystem = null;
        
for (URL classpathURL : classpathURLs) {
    try {
        if (classpathURL.toString().startsWith("jar:file:/")) {
            fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(classpathURL.toURI(), new HashMap<>());
            path = fileSystem.getPath("/");
        } else {
            fileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault();
            path = fileSystem.getPath(classpathURL.getPath());
        }
               
        PathMatcher pathMatcher = fileSystem.getPathMatcher("glob:**/*.properties");
        Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                if (pathMatcher.matches(path)) {
                    String resourceName = (path.getClass().getName().contains("ZipPath") ? path.toString() : path.toFile().getName());
                    // resource found - do further processing
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException ex) {
        // handle exceptions
    }
}
```

As you can see, a list of `classpathURL`'s will be returned from the `classpathHelper`. These URL's starts either with `jar:file:/` or with `file:/`.
For each case a proper `FileSystem` and `Path` will be created.
Finally the `java.nio.PathMatcher` in conjunction with a `SimpleFileVisitor` will be used to find the required resources.

Answer (score 1):

`ClassLoader.getResources("name")` enumerates all resources with "name". But not enumerates "files" in the directory named as "name".

For example you can have two jars which contain files `/my.properties`. In this case method `ClassLoader.getResources("my.properties")` returns two URL for each file.

Comment: I do not need a specific file like `my.properties` but all `*.properties` files.
Anyway - Thanks for answering

Comment: There are no regular expressions or any tools.